# How to preserve a state in UDF in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

There is a way to preserve state in a User Defined Function in pyspark?
I need to create a cache (a simple map could be a dictionary).

Maybe using `sc._conf.getAll()` inside the function, or by using a temporary table?

Comment: The use of "best way" in the question sets it up for opinion based answers which stackoverflow isn't set up to handle well. Can you rephrase the question to get less opinion based answers?

Comment: Tanks @JasonAller!